# Rails - Pass collection to ActiveModel object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, parameters, datatables, activemodel

I am using rails to make a [datatable](https://datatables.net) that paginates with Ajax, and I am following [railscast #340](http://railscasts.com/episodes/340-datatables) to do so.

This episode makes use of a normal ActiveModel Class called `ProductsDatatable` or in my case `OrdersDatatable` to create and configure the table. My question has to do with ruby syntax in this class. I am trying to pass a collection of orders to the `OrdersDatatable` object, from the controller. I want to access this collection in the `fetch_orders` method.

I create the table object like this in order.rb:

```
@datatable = OrdersDatatable.new(view_context)
@datatable.shop_id = @current_shop.id
@datatable.orders_list = @orders # which is Order.in_process
```

And my `OrdersDatatable` class looks like this: (the important parts which probably need to change is the second line in `initialize` and the first line in `fetch_orders`)

```
class OrdersDatatable
  include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
  include ActionView::Helpers::DateHelper
  include ActionView::Helpers::TagHelper

  delegate :params, :h, :link_to, :number_to_currency, to: :@view

  attr_accessor :shop_id, :orders_list

  def initialize(view)
    @view = view
    @orders_list = self.orders_list
  end

  def current_shop
    Shop.find(shop_id)
  end

  def as_json(options = {})
    {
      sEcho: params[:sEcho].to_i,
      iTotalRecords: orders.count,
      iTotalDisplayRecords: orders.count,
      aaData: data
    }
  end

private


  def data
    orders.map do |order|
      [
        order.id,
        order.name,
        h(time_tag(order.date_placed.in_time_zone)),
        order.state,
        order.source,
        order.payment_status,
        h(order.delivered? ? 'shipped' : 'unshipped'),
        h(number_to_currency order.final_total, unit: order.currency.symbol),
        h(link_to 'details', edit_admin_shop_order_path(current_shop, order)),
        h(link_to 'delete', admin_shop_order_path(current_shop, order), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } ),
      ]
    end
  end

  def orders
    @orders ||= fetch_orders
  end

  def fetch_orders
    orders = orders_list.order("#{sort_column} #{sort_direction}")
    orders = orders.page(page).per_page(per_page)
    if params[:sSearch].present?
      orders = orders.where("title like :search", search: "%#{params[:sSearch]}%")
    end
    orders
  end

  def page
    params[:iDisplayStart].to_i/per_page + 1
  end

  def per_page
    params[:iDisplayLength].to_i > 0 ? params[:iDisplayLength].to_i : 10
  end

  def sort_column
    columns = %w[id name date_placed state source payment_status delivered final_total]
    columns[params[:iSortCol_0].to_i]
  end

  def sort_direction
    params[:sSortDir_0] == "desc" ? "desc" : "asc"
  end
end
```

When I change the first line in `fetch_orders` to this

```
orders = Order.in_process.order("#{sort_column} #{sort_direction}")
```

which is the hard-coded equivalent, it does work. So I just need the correct syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: If you've got an array, and want to sort it, use the `sort_by` method:

```
orders = orders_list.sort_by{|order| "#{order.sort_column} #{order.sort_direction}"}
```

Long answer: The reason your original code doesn't work is that in this case

```
Order.in_process.order("#{sort_column} #{sort_direction}")
```

you are **building** a query.  `in_process` is a named scope (passing in some conditions), and `.order` tells rails what to order the query by.  Then, when it runs out of chained methods, the query executes (runs some sql) and gets the records out of the DB to build a collection of objects.

Once you are working with a collection of objects, you can't call the `.order` method on it, as that's just used to assemble an sql query.  You need to use `Array#sort_by` instead.  `sort_by` takes a code block, into which is passed each object in the collection (as `order` in my example but you could call it anything, it's just a variable name).

BTW, if you just want to call a method on all the objects to sort them, you can use a "shortcut syntax"  like `.sort_by(&:methodname)`.  This uses a little trick of ruby called `Symbol#to_proc` (http://railscasts.com/episodes/6-shortcut-blocks-with-symbol-to-proc).

So, for example, if there was a method in Order like so

```
def sort_string
  "#{self.sort_column} #{self.sort_direction}"
end
```

then you could change your code to

```
orders = orders_list.sort_by(&:sort_string)
```

which is neat.

Comment: The problem is not incorrect sorting, but the collection is not correctly accessed.

Comment: I need a way to actually access orders_list. See my edit

Comment: I just told you how to sort the `orders_list` array.  I'm not sure what you mean by "access" here.

Comment: also "it doesn't work" is vague:  do you mean it blows up, or that it gives you some different results to what you expected?  if the latter then say what results it gives you.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an array, then you can sort like this.

```
   orders = orders_list.sort! {|a,b| a.sort_column <=> b.sort_direction}
```